Can logical inference be based on non-contradiction?
In philosophy it was once common to claim that logical truths are based on the law of non-contradiction. Today it is more common to refer to modality, as in: an inference is deductive if the conclusion follows necessarily from the premises. Was this weakening of the logical enterprise motivated by a specific example of deduction that is not based on non-contradiction? Alternatively, has there been any formal proof that logic or some subset of logic can or cannot be based on contradiction alone?

Mainly the modal shift is through constructive intuitionistic logic with flexible Kripke frame semantics, and most paraconsistent logic just weaken LNC to only introduce negation out of the purely positive fragment without explosion, such as minimal logic…

It is not that there was a weakening, non-contradiction is just not enough by itself. The standard approach to logical consequence is still "based on the law of non-contradiction", to the extent that it makes sense, see SEP:"The model-centered approach to logical consequence takes the validity of an argument to be absence of counterexample." One still has to specify what counts as a model and what gets interpreted in models ("non-logical vocabulary"). Modality comes into play in explicating the range of models.

@Conifold, "weakening" in the sense that necessity is a weaker condition than contradiction. That is, anything that is contradictory is necessarily false, but not everything necessarily false is contradictory.

If the "necessity" is logical necessity then necessarily false and contradictory (inconsistent) are the same. And either way we still have to spell out what counts as "logical form", i.e. what can be varied in models.

I'm inclined to agree with Conifold's comment that there is not much difference. Aristotle frequently uses modal language such as 'necessary' and 'impossible' when describing logical relationships. Contradiction is perhaps the most obvious kind of impossibility, but in ancient logic something that goes against LNC or the law of identity is also impossible. And in any version of classical logic, any logical falsehood or logical impossibility entails a contradiction.
